# Getting 403 error when running Python mechanize within docker container

Tags: python, docker, web-scraping, mechanize

I've built a Python script with the module mechanize which scrapes data from a website. When I run the code on my python environment on my localhost, everything works fine. Now i've started to transfer my code in a docker container which runs the same Python version as I'm using on my PC, but the website throws an 403 Error.

The following code describes the mechanize browser settings:

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; 360SE)"
base_url = "https://www.somewebsiteurl.com"
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', user_agent)]
```

Does anyone have an idea about the settings, that a can modify to get the same results within the container?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this docker container running on you local pc as well, or is it remote somewhere?

Comment: @Karl it's also running on my local pc. That's why this error is confusing me.